# Styling VALUE in Jquery-ui-autocomplete

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i've read lots of questions alike but still can't figure it out

what i mean by 'value' is the text that the users inserts in the input
i dont know if im making myself clear

help it's much appreciated

Comment: Do you want to style the `input` textbox where you type to get autocomplete?

Comment: yes, thats exactly what i need, more precisely the text in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CSS.

```
.ui-autocomplete-input {
    word-spacing: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the plugin's `select` event where you can get its value.

```
select: function(e, ui){
   alert(ui.item.value);
}
```